# Characterizing weak instruments bias with more than one endogenous variable

Tags: econometrics, bias, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

With a single endogenous variable, it is well known that a weak instrumental variable (or set of weak instrumental variables*) will bias 2SLS estimates toward OLS estimates.  But how can one characterize the bias of 2SLS when there are two or more endogenous variables with weak instruments?  Is it possible to sign the bias?  If so, how?

*I recognize that overidentified systems can be worse than OLS if the instruments are quite bad.